# Dell Equallogic PS 6210 is not Booting up After Power Outage

Tags: storage-area-network, dell, dell-equallogic

Our EqualLogic PS 6210 is not booting up properly after the power outage, unfortunately it is not under warranty

We can power it on, the disks are blinking and both controller is powered on (but either of them are not active). It stays few minutes before it shut off itself

I tried both management and serial port to access the console, to no avail.

Does anybody have an idea on this issue

Comment: Connect to iDRAC and check System Event Log. See what components are failed. If iDRAC is not available I would suspect the power supplies or the motherboard. iDRAC ports are 100Mbps. Make sure the switchport supports 100Mbps and that the iDRAC port is connected and configured.

Comment: iDRAC is not available.

Comment: Try to replace motherboard

Comment: It has two controller (no mother board), either of them should be active at a time. For some reason, neither of them are coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting the controller separately ? have you got an output on the serial console (RS232 port) ?

Comment: Tried different combination of controller and power supply. nothing shows when connected using serial console.

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange. Are you using the right serial settings and a proper, checked cable ? The boot loader should pop up even if the firmware media is missing.

If you plug out the controller you should be able to see a micro SD card with the Equallogic OS (firmware). Check if they are present.

Serial settings : 9600, no parity, one stop bit, 8 data bits. NO FLOWCONTROL

Comment: I'm using the serial cable which came with EqualLogic, with the same serial setting you have mentioned. Unfortunately, it did not work.  The micro SD card is present on both controller